# exporting data from gtm or ga to excel or csv or my own data base

Tags: mysql, excel, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to store my event data to a server or excel to use it for insight and email data for my coworkers to get the result in a format that I want.if there is a way to do that with google analytics that's good too.

Comment: Do you require mySQL answer, or are you ok with solutions with the use of other languages / technologies?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Google Analytics API** and **Google Apps Script** to access your **Google Analytics** data from **Google Sheets**. This is powerful because it allows you to utilize all the great features of Google Sheets with your analytics data, such as easy **sharing**, collaboration, charting and visualization tools.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/reporting-apps-script